# AWS DynamoDB scan returns Item array - how to request Key-Value dictionary by primary key?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

In order to avoid delay when fetching data, I want to download/cache my whole DynamoDB (10MB, 120'000 entries, 3 values each) on launch of my javascript application so some data can be displayed immediately while updated data gets requested and displayed shortly after (in case the entry got updated after the cache time).

For the initial download, the app makes a httprequest to my lambda function which in turn calls

`await dynamo.scan({ TableName: tableName })`.

This returns a response that looks like the following:

`{"Items":[{"key":"personA","address":"ABC"},{"key":"personB","address":"XYZ"}],"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}`

In my app I want to display the address for a specific person. Since the return type is an array I am afraid that I have to iterate over every entry and check for `entry['key']='personA'`. I would much rather do something like `Items['personA']` since I have set `key` as the primary key of the DynamoDB.

Is there another operation that I can make use of in order to receive a dictionary indexed by the `key` column of the data?

So basically my goal would be to get

`{"Items":{"personA":{"address":"ABC"}},{"personB":{"address":"XYZ"}},"Count":2,"ScannedCount":2}`

(Dictionary with the value of `key` as the actual key instead of a rather inconvenient array)

*Just in case my use case sounds dangerous - the app is not for retail customers, it's not available to anyone who should not have access to this data anyways.*

Comment: I don't know which programming language you're doing this with, but the obvious solution would be to the entire array and then convert it to a dictionary. It's trivial but the downside is that temporarily your memory use doubles (you have both array and dictionary in memory). If that bothers you, you can ask Scan to read just a single page of results (in some languages, this is the only function you get from the AWS SDK!) and copy the contents of each page into the dictionary, page by page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there another operation that I can make use of in order to receive a dictionary indexed by the `key` column of the data?

No, DynamoDB currently does not have such an API with the option for you to transform the data to the format you described.

---

So basically you are left with the following two options:

1. Use the Scan response and build the index/dictionary yourself.

   - **Advantage:** you can reuse this index to look up other people
   - **Disadvantage:** might be slow to build the initial index since it requires a full list traversal
2. Retrieve the data using [`GetItem`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_GetItem.html) by providing the primary key.

   - **Advantage:** you can quickly get only the data you want
   - **Disadvantage:** you have to make an HTTP request for every person. This might be too much overhead although [HTTP connection can be kept live and reused](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html).